# XCode Archive: `Binary and Entitlements` section is blank

Tags: ios, xcode

My XCode->Archive window no longer shows `application-identifier, keychain-access-groups, get-task-allow, com.apple.developer.team-identifier values.` under Binary and Entitlements section. Next to the `Sample.app`, it shows `4 entitlements`. But when I expand the app, it is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please [image: expand this window]. And then expand the Entitlements.
So it can show the details as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

once you have the IPA exported you can check the entitlements using this command

```
codesign -d --entitlements :- /path/to/MyGreatApp.app
```

And If you want to check the entitlements of the profile with which it is signed you can use this command

```
security cms -D -i /path/to/MyGreatApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision
```

More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2318/_index.html). Hope this helps Cheers!